# Condensing buttons or spreading them out on mobile

Tags: mobile, buttons

Designing an app with a map feature which has to contain two separate buttons for layer changing and location finding. Originally had the two button on the bottom right, for easy access for the thumb but I heard condensing buttons too close together in mobile can cause the user to accidentally press what they don't want. So spreading the buttons out like in the right image is better, but I feel this creates more physical 'reach'?

Should controls like this be kept together or apart?

[image]

Comment: Users will be navigating your app with their thumbs. As long as the touch area for each button is large enough, keep as many controls as you can near where the user can reach without much effort. If you want to keep the buttons away from each-other, why move them clear across the screen? Just increase the gaps a little.

Answer (score 1):

First, how often are your users expected to use these buttons? Will there be more buttons? 
Layers option doesn't look like an often-used one (without context).

After answering this, there are options:

1. Leave a more often-used button near the thumb, and move the other
   away (or somewhere into the menu)
2. Leave buttons together, but add some margin for less slips
3. Make one of the buttons disappear sometimes (Like "Find me" button, when you are already on screen).